# Do moments define distributions?

Tags: probability, probability-theory, probability-distributions, random-variables, moment-problem

Do moments define distributions?

Suppose I have two random variables $X$ and $Y$. If I know $E\left[X^k\right] = E\left[Y^k\right]$ for every $k \in \mathbb N$, can I say that $X$ and $Y$ have the same distribution?

Comment: See http://mathoverflow.net/questions/3525/when-are-probability-distributions-completely-determined-by-their-moments

Comment: In general, no. At least not without additional assumptions. An example of such an assumption is that $E[e^{\rho|X|}]<\infty$ for some $\rho>0$.

Comment: @StefanHansen, Is there a list of conditions for this to hold?

Answer (score 16, accepted):

This question is known as *(indeterminate) moment problem* and has been first considered by Stieltjes and Hamburger. In general, the answer to your question is: No, distributions are not uniquely determined by their moments.

The standard counterexample is the following (see e.g. Rick Durrett, Probability: Theory and Examples): The lognormal distribution

$$p(x) := \frac{1}{x\sqrt{2\pi}} \exp \left(- \frac{(\log x)^2}{2} \right)$$

and the "perturbed" lognormal distribution

$$q(x) := p(x) (1+ \sin(2\pi \log(x)))$$

have the same moments.

Much more interesting is the question under which additional assumptions the moments *are* determining. @StefanHansen already mentioned the existence of exponential moments, but obviously that's a strong condition. Some years ago Christian Berg showed that so-called Hankel matrices are strongly related to this problem; in fact one can show that the moment problem is determinante if and only if the smallest eigenvalue of the Hankel matrix converges to $0$. For a more detailed discussion see e.g. [this introduction](http://web.williams.edu/Mathematics/sjmiller/public_html/book/papers/jcmp.pdf) or [Christian Berg's paper](http://www.sciencedirect.com/science/article/pii/0377042795000992).

Comment: Thank you again for this great answer and links! It seems like they are above my current level but nonetheless I appreciate them. Why is it though that the the condition mentioned by @StefanHansen is sufficient? That would imply that the characteristic function of $X$ is $\phi(t) = \sum \frac{(it)^n}{n!}E[X^n]$ only for $t \le \rho$, am I right? (If it held for all $t$ we would have equality of characteristic functions and so $X$ and $Y$ have the same distribution).

Comment: @Ant Yes, you are right. However, it suffices to have $\mathbb{E}e^{\imath \, t X} = \mathbb{E}e^{\imath \, t Y}$ for $|t| \leq \varrho$ to conclude $X=Y$ in distribution (i.e. if two characteristic functions are identical in a neighborhood of zero, then they are identical). This is not obvious, see e.g. Kawata's book (Fourier Analysis in Probability Theory), Theorem 9.6.2.

Comment: Ah, I see, perfect! Thanks :D

Comment: Hi! I'm sorry to bother after all this time, but I was looking at the charachteristic function page on wikipedia (https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Characteristic_function_(probability_theory)#Continuity) at the section of the Polya theorem,  and there is an example of two charactheristic functions equal in a neighborhood of $0$ but different elsewhere. Would't that be against the result from Kawata? What am I misunderstanding?

Comment: @Ant It seems that I wasn't reading Kawata's result carefully enough. He proves the result only for characteristic functions with an additional regularity property.

Comment: Could you please list more conditions which makes the suggestion hold? The simpler the better :-).

Answer (score 1):

A construction of two discrete probability measures on $\mathbb{R}$ having the same moments is given in Varadhan's '*Probability Theory*', page 23.

For those without access, one can consider the family of holomorphic functions 
$$\Pi_{0\leq n\leq N}\left(1 - \frac{z}{e^n} \right) 
$$
which converge uniformly on compact sets to define an entire function, say
$$A(z) = \sum\limits_{m=0}a_mz^m.
$$
Thus for each $n$, we have 
$$0 = \sum\limits_{m=0} a_m(e^n)^m = \sum\limits_{m=0}(e^m)^n \Re(a_m). \ \ \ \ \ (\star)
$$
Define $f(m) = \max(0,\Re(a_m))$ and $g(m) = \max(0,- \Re(a_m))$.
$f(m)$ and $g(m)$ are both nonnegative with $f(m) - g(m) = \Re(a_m)$ and we define two probabilities supported on $\lbrace e^k : k = 0, 1\dots\rbrace$ by 
$$
\mu\left(\lbrace e^k \rbrace\right) = \frac{f(k)}{\sum f(m)},\ \nu\left(\lbrace e^k \rbrace \right) = \frac{g(k)}{\sum g(m)}.
$$
One can check, using the definition of $A$ and $(\star)$, that the sums in the denominators do actually converge, are positive and that they are in fact the same number, call it $S$.

That these probabilities above have well defined moments, for example $\sum\limits_{m}(e^m)^n\mu\left(\lbrace e^m\rbrace\right) = \sum\limits_{m}(e^n)^m\mu\left(\lbrace e^m\rbrace\right)$, follows from the convergence of $A$.

And finally, by another application of $(\star)$, we have
$$\mathbb{E}_{\mu}[x^n] = \sum\limits_{k}(e^k)^n\mu\left(\lbrace e^k\rbrace\right) = \sum\limits_{k}(e^k)^n \frac{f(k)}{S} = \frac{1}{S}\sum\limits_{k}(e^k)^n f(k) = \frac{1}{S}\sum\limits_{k}(e^k)^n g(k) = \mathbb{E}_{\nu}[x^n].$$

Answer (score -7):

A moment is an integral of a weighted probability distribution, which is a number. So the mapping is "many-to-one" which is not invertible. So an integral cannot serve as the definition for an integrand.

Comment: What's wrong with my answer?

Comment: It is a little naive. I did not ask for something like "If I know $\int_\mathbb R f(x) = 1$, then can I know $f(x)$?" - In this case your answer would have been valid! I asked for something different, and as it turns out with additional assumption you indeed can "reverse" the mapping :) I don't mean to discourage you though! This is a very nice site and one can learn a lot! :)

Comment: You did ask whether moments set distributions. They cannot define distributions, because the mapping from moment to distribution is not unique. That is a perfectly valid mathematical answer.

Comment: Okay. Now let me ask a slightly different question: "Given that exsists $\rho > 0$ such that $\mathbb E[e^{\rho |X|}] < \infty$, then do moments define distributions?". Your answer would be "moments cannot define distributions, because the mapping from moment to distribution is not unique". As it turns out, in that case they can! So your explanation is a little bit naive: nothing in your reasoning seems to change if we take that additional hypothesis, but in this case it would be wrong. Also, it's worth noting that I am talking about a countable number of integrals, not one or finite number.

Comment: But now you gave constraints. In your original question you didn't.

Comment: Yes but your answer would have failed to take that into account, because after all is just a number of integrals that define the integrand, with a seemingly innocuous condition.The conclusion you get is right but for the wrong reasons.. It does not add any insights and it is little more than "it's false because it's false" kinda of explanation. At least I feel this was, you may feel differently but I explained why I am not satisfied with this answer.

Comment: The mapping $\mu\mapsto E[X^k]$ is many-to-one, where $\mu$ is a distribution and $X\sim \mu$, but that does not imply $\mu\mapsto (EX,EX^2,EX^3,\dots)$ is many-to-one. You need to justify your answer.