# Constructing the MGF from the mean and Variance

Tags: probability, statistics, probability-distributions, standard-deviation

If I have the mean, variance, PDF and CDF of a random variable $X$
how to easily construct the MGF.

Comment: You only need the CDF; the MGF is $\int_{-\infty}^\infty e^{tx}dF(x)$. If the PDF exists, you can get it from that instead.

Comment: Thanks for the comment, you mean like this: $M_X(t) = \mathbb{E}[e^{tX}] = \int^{\infty}_{0} e^{tx}f(x)dx$, where $X$ is positive random variable

Comment: That's it exactly. By contrast, [even infinitely many moments might not fix the distribution](https://math.stackexchange.com/a/1166855), so don't determine the MGF. (Knowing $M_X$ on $\Bbb Q$ is enough, provided $M_X$ is everywhere finite, but knowing it on $\Bbb N$ isn't.)